# How to solve apt "package cannot be configured because package is in a different version" errors?

Tags: apt

I can't say what steps brought me into this:

```
→ sudo apt-get upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: error processing libtiff4 (--configure):
 libtiff4:i386 3.9.5-1ubuntu1.1 cannot be configured because libtiff4:k386 is in a different version (3.9.5-1ubuntu1)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libtiff4
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The following commands all end up in the same error:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get --fix-missing install
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

How to solve these kind of problems? And what did I do wrong?

**UPDATE**
I managed to get apt working again by downgrading to previous version (3.9.5-1ubuntu1). However, next upgrade led to the same problem. But there is more info now:

```
(Reading database ... 
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `libtiff4:k386' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
(Reading database ... 281166 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libtiff4 3.9.5-1ubuntu1 (using .../libtiff4_3.9.5-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libtiff4 ...
dpkg: error processing libtiff4 (--configure):
 libtiff4:i386 3.9.5-1ubuntu1.1 cannot be configured because libtiff4:k386 is in a different version (3.9.5-1ubuntu1)
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 libtiff4
```

So the real problem seems to be the missing `libtiff4:k386` package. And `k386` seems like a stupid typo somewhere.

I tracked down the file that introduces the typo:

```
**/var/lib/dpkg/status**

Package: libtiff4
Status: install ok half-configured
Multi-Arch: same
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 528
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: k386
Source: tiff
Version: 3.9.5-1ubuntu1
Config-Version: 3.9.5-1ubuntu1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11), libjpeg62 (>= 6b1), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
Pre-Depends: multiarch-support
Description: Tag Image File Format (TIFF) library
 libtiff is a library providing support for the Tag Image File Format
 (TIFF), a widely used format for storing image data.  This package
 includes the shared library.
Homepage: http://libtiff.maptools.org
Original-Maintainer: Jay Berkenbilt <qjb@debian.org>
```

Fixing the typo solves the problem.

Comment: BTW, what is :i386 and :k386 next to package name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, I remove the offending package first, and try to reinstall the packages afterwards.  More than likely, you have some other repos enabled that provides the same packages and that leads to a conflict.

If this doesn't work, and you're SURE that this is coming from the base repositories you can force it (--force-yes).  However, this should only be done if you're sure that the package you need won't compromise the integrity of your system.

Comment: It's libtiff4 (image file format library). A ton of software depend on it. I can not simply remove and install it.

Comment: Have you tried apt-get upgrade libtiff4 (by itself)?  I would double-check that your repository matches your current Ubuntu version (e.g. lsb_release -a) and compare that to /etc/apt/sources.list

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-all <package-name>

sudo apt-get install <package-name>
```

Comment: can you elaborate how this would help?

Comment: This worked for me so far. I hope it didn't brake packages that were dependent (on `libpng12-0` in my case).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right about that version of the package having a typo, :k386 for i386.  It's fixed now in the current version.

I had a somewhat different problem getting libtiff4:i386 to install.  I had to re-install libtiff4, then it worked.  (during an upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04).